# Special characters in filename java

Tags: java, file, file-writing

I'm trying to write a file with special characters in filename, for examplo "tééé ê.mp3", but the filename always stay with "?" instead the character "é", I tried a several methods but i didn't found a solution:

```
String musicName = new String("tééé ê.mp3".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
OutputStreamWriter bw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(FILE_PATH+"musics/"+musicName), "UTF-8");
bw.write(data);
bw.close();
```

I tried this way too.

```
OutputStreamWriter bw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(URLDecoder.decode(FILE_PATH+"musics/tééé ê.mp3", "UTF-8")), "UTF-8");
bw.write(data);
bw.close();
```

Comment: Some file systems even don't support such file names. Why do you want to write such?

Comment: because the system what i'm building have to accept upload files with special characters in file name.

Comment: Leaving Java aside: on this system (which one, btw??), can you create a file with these characters in its name?

Comment: Yes, i'm using Mac Os system, and i can create files with special characters manually.

Comment: @pedrodurek: that does not depend on the operating system (itself), but on the file system used. For instance FAT can't whereas NTFS can.

Comment: it's HFS+ system file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `Files`:

```
final Path target = Paths.get("tééé ê.mp3");

try (
    final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(target, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
) {
    // write
}
```

Now, if this is a problem that your filesystem does not support such filenames, you will get an `InvalidPathException`; unlike `File`, the new API refuses to create file names which may end up being unreadable.

If this is the case that you can indeed not create the path, well, you'll have to find a way to escape and unescape somewhat; maybe write an alternate name to some sort of database or something.

Note that `InvalidPathException` is *unchecked*; you therefore have to catch this exception explicitly. Also note that you may get this exception if the current character coding used by the JVM is just not suitable to generate the filename.

Comment: File filename stayed "t%E9%E9%E9 %EA.mp3". Do you know how can i fix it?

Comment: Hmm, it appears that the problem is with your terminal then; maybe it just cannot display such characters?

Comment: What is the encoding used by your JVM?

Comment: Well, you should really use UTF-8 instead

Comment: I put the project in apache and it worked, I think it could be something with the eclipse. Do you know what it could be and how to fix it?