# Java Encoding - 'é' becomes '?'

Tags: java, linux, encoding

Problem:

```
File dir = new File (path);
```

With path containing the character 'é'.
When I run the application on Windows, the folders are created with the correct names.
But when running the application on Linux, 'é' will be replaced with '?'

Any solutions or workarounds?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just your terminal that doesn't know how to show non-ascii characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Special characters in filename java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476663/special-characters-in-filename-java)

Comment: What are your locale settings?

Comment: This might have to do with the difference in default charsets on each system. You may want to check the output of ```System.out.println( Charset.defaultCharset() );``` on each system separately and compare.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], specifically how `path` is derived.